# Receive data using Async Javascript call

Tags: javascript, http, callback, dom-events

I wish to request data from a web service endpoint( say "http://www.example.com") using javascript.

After retrieving it , there will be a callback function to process the response ( which will be a JSON object )

How do I go about writing it? A skeleton code will do.

Will it be something like:

```
<script>

function callback(data)
{
    // the response text would be processed here.
}
       url="http://www.example.com";
       var script = document.createElement('script');
       script.src = url;
       script.onload=callback;
       document.body.appendChild(script);        
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the code you posted?

Comment: Why do you expect response text to be passed to the script's `onload` handler? It looks like you're trying to get arbitrary data via a `script` element. What does the actual response from the actual url look like?

Comment: Yes,I tried it in Chrome. no response.

Comment: @amnotiam http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info|revisions&intoken=edit&titles=Main%20Page&format=json  How do I grab the response text?

Comment: @SHOUBHIKBOSE: You can't get that data via a `script` element, because it isn't valid JavaScript.

Comment: @amnotiam okay, could you help me accomplish the above task using javascript?

Comment: @SHOUBHIKBOSE: It isn't possible for a client to get that sort of data from a different domain. It's a security limitation. You'll probably need to have your server fetch it, and then have the client request it from your server.

Comment: Wikimedia API which Wikipedia use supports JSONP `callback` argument.

Comment: @JuicyScripter: Ah, you're right. I added `&callback=test`, and got the proper JSONP response. You should add an answer.

Comment: @SHOUBHIKBOSE: Well, until an answer is added, add `&callback=some_func` to the end of the url (you can use something different than `some_func`), then get rid of the `script.onload=callback;` line, and change the name of your `callback` function to `some_func`, or whatever name you chose. You could do `&callback=callback` I suppose, but I'd use a different name personally.

Comment: @amnotiam Thanks a lot. I'll try that out :) and in the meantime, also add the answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by [@JuicyScripter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155033/juicy-scripter) in the comment above...

> *"Wikimedia API which Wikipedia use supports JSONP callback argument."*

This means that you can add a callback to the query...

```
var url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info|revisions&intoken=edit&titles=Main%20Page&format=json&callback=my_callback";
```

Notice at the end I added `&callback=my_callback`. What will happen is that instead of sending a JSON response like...

```
{
    query: {
        pages: {
            15580374: {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...it will now be wrapped in a function call. This will be valid JavaScript, so your `script` request will execute the function, and pass the data.

```
my_callback({
    query: {
        pages: {
            15580374: {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So all you need is a callback function that has the same name as the function you gave in the query...

```
function my_callback( data ) {
    console.log( data );
}
```

Make sure this function is globally available.

Then get rid of the `onload` line, and your code should just work...

```
var url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info|revisions&intoken=edit&titles=Main%20Page&format=json&callback=my_callback";
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = url;
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

When the script arrives and runs, it will invoke your function passing it the data requested.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info|revisions&intoken=edit&titles=Main%20Page&format=json&callback=test does not give the token anymore. Removing callback=test gave the token.

Comment: @SHOUBHIKBOSE: I don't know what you mean, but perhaps the "token" has some sort of request limitation associated with it? You'll need to study the API to know.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the examples here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

This will give you everything you need to get started and more, the following example has been taken from the link:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    tags: "cat",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
      if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
```

Here the jSON get request is sending 3 parameters: `tags`, `tagmode` and `format` in the url as a GET request (the same as http://mysite.com?name=me&mood=happy).

The `function(data)` is processing the results of the request

Read the link for more indepth detail and examples.